# Is it possible to force the Telerik MVC MultiSelect to post just an ID back to the controller?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to migrate a Html.ListBoxFor() over to a Html.Telerik().MultiSelectFor() to gain a bit of fancy UI, but the HTTP form posts are incompatible with the Model, and it seems excessive to make a new model binder to avoid it.

```
public class Settings
{
  public int[] UserIds { get; set; }

  public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> UserSelectList { get; set; }
}
```

When I use the Html.ListBoxFor helper, the HTTP form post includes just the value of the Select List Item (i.e. an array of UserIds), as expected.

```
UserIds[0] = 1
UserIds[1] = 2

@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.UserIds, Model.UserSelectList)
```

When I use the Kendo MultiSelect, the HTTP form post includes two properties.  Which is not expected.

```
UserIds[0].Text = Adrian
UserIds[0].Value = 1
...

@Kendo().MultiSelectFor(model => Model.UserIds).BindTo(Model.UserSelectList)
```

Does anyone know a way to get the Kendo MultiSelect to just post the id value back, or is there a ready-made Model Binder?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to set the Primitive value to true which will get only the value list.

```
    .ValuePrimitive(true)
```

For reference: 
[Is Primitive Sample](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/multiselect/mvvm)

Comment: If above solution has answered your question then please mark it as answered for others to find it helpful.